# Running gruntfile from devDependencies module

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm

I am doing some `.js` framework testing. I have in my `package.JSON`, inside devDependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "myFramework": "https://github.com/myRepo/myFramework/tarball/master",
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    // etc
```

This works as expected and install this framework in my `./node_modules/myFramework`

This module (myFramework) compiles a file that I need. So it needs to run a gruntfile.js to compile. Those compiled files will be used in my local gruntfile. Any ideas on how to do this?

I thought about using npm script, something like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "node node_modules/myFramework/Gruntfile.js",
```

But this example didn't work. I had a `console.log('Test');` inside the `myFramework` gruntfile and nothing logged...

Answer (score 0):

You should never have to run any Gruntfile tasks other that the repo where you currently are.

Much like your package.json file, there should be one and only one Gruntfile.js per repository.

This cannot be stressed enough. Scenarios that require multiple Gruntfiles can really be solved by using simpler setups and infrastructure. The fact that jQuery has it's own Gruntfile.js in the source repository is absolutely irrelevant to your build flow. Another package may use a Makefile instead or any other means of creating the end product. You should never have to deal with what tools the third-party library author uses to produce the build.

Read a more detailed analysis at: http://thanpol.as/grunt/Managing-large-scale-projects-with-Grunt/

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I only have one `gruntfile` in my repo. What I want is to use/import a task from a gruntfile in another repo.

Comment: This task should be published as a stand alone Grunt plugin

Answer (score 0):

One idea that just came up is that i can copy and paste the task that compiles the files (from the node module gruntfile) inside my local gruntfile. 
Changing of course the path from the task to reflect that now the files are located at  `/node_modules/myFramework/`

I leave the question open anyway to check if there is another (maybe better) way to this.